# Cannot jump ahead to a later part of the embedded video until it has downloaded

Tags: flv

We have flv file played by Adobe Flash player- but cant play the middle of file, while its all is not downloaded. The flv file is generated from live stream by Flash media live encoder with timecode enabled.

Comment: Is your webserver configured to stream flv files?

Comment: no, we have apache on default settings

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to ensure that your webserver (you don't say which) is configured to stream the media files. Look up RTMP streaming, your player (you don't say which) needs to be able to cope with this also, so when you skip to the middle it passes a parameter to the server requesting the appropriate part of the video stream.

Comment: We are using Apache 2.0 and player is http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback_101.swf

Comment: We also have Wowza, but cant find tutorial how to play flv files

Comment: I've had success streaming flv and mp4 files using flowplayer (http://flowplayer.org/) the site includes tutorial code and links to what you need to setup on apache to get it working.